# Axios: how to cancel request inside request interceptor properly?

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to cancel the request if there's no token, so I do like this:

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  if (!getToken()) {
    console.log("interceptors: no access token");
  } else {
    config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + getToken().accessToken;
    return config;
  }
});
```

But in negative scenario there's an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancelToken' of undefined`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot use the token inside the interceptors but instead throw `Cancel`

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  throw new axios.Cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Refer to this post:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/583

Comment: Will it cause `function (error) {...}` code branch runs or falls into `.catch()` later only?

Comment: I am guessing you meant where will the code flow when you throw the `axios.Cancel()`. I have tried this, and the cancel will appear as an error in the `catch()` later directly.

Comment: This is incorrect as of writing (that you cannot use cancel token's inside an interceptor) and doesn't handle all use cases, such as if a request has already started and you now need to cancel all requests (e.g. the user has been logged out due to session expiry). For this see vijay's solution.

Comment: the OP asked for a solution in a request interceptor

Comment: But it seems like Cancel method does not exist on Axios instance strangely. How can be this achieved if we are using interceptor on Axios instance?

Answer (score 32):

### Axios `v0.22.0` and higher

As per the [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation), cancellation is now pretty straightforward with the `AbortController` class

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  /* some logic */
  const controller = new AbortController();

  if (needToCancelRequest) {
    controller.abort();
  }

  return {
    ...config,
    signal: controller.signal
  };
});
```

##### Browser Compatibility

You might be tempted to do a pretty concise `signal: AbortSignal.abort()` instead. Please, note that it is much less supported than the solution above. See [`AbortSignal.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort#browser_compatibility) vs [`new AbortController().abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort#browser_compatibility) compatibility.

### Axios before `v0.22.0`

This is a solution taken from the [axios issue on github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1497#issuecomment-425463114)

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  /* some logic */
  return {
    ...config,
    cancelToken: new CancelToken((cancel) => {
      if (needToCancelRequest) {
       cancel('Cancel repeated request')
      }
    })
  };
});
```

Comment: Note this is [deprecated](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) as of axios v0.22 and suggests use of the `AbortController`

Comment: This answer is correct, but CancelToken is deprecated.  Use an abort controller instead, [using AbortSignal as shown in this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71382464/3670756)

Answer (score 9):

So for whatever reason none of these answers worked for me. Here is what did.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const cfg = {
      ...config,
      signal: controller.signal,
    };
    controller.abort('We gotta cancel this');
    return cfg;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

Thing I learned from this: `AbortController` is native to javascript/node.

Comment: controller.abort doesn't expect any argument by the way but it's the right way to do it

Comment: Here is the TS definition for the `abort` method
`(method) AbortController.abort(reason?: any): void (+1 overload)`

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented this in this way. I am not sure if this is the best solution, but for my use case is useful.
My idea is not to cancel the last request. I would like to cancel previous requests to the same endpoint, and let the last one to do his job. For that reason I keep track of the request that are being executed.

```
// I keep track of the current requests that are being executed
const currentExecutingRequests = {};

axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (req) => {
        let originalRequest = req;

        if (currentExecutingRequests[req.url]) {
            const source = currentExecutingRequests[req.url];
            delete currentExecutingRequests[req.url];
            source.cancel();
        }

        const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
        const source = CancelToken.source();
        originalRequest.cancelToken = source.token;
        currentExecutingRequests[req.url] = source;

        // here you could add the authorization header to the request

        return originalRequest;
    },
    (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        if (currentExecutingRequests[response.request.responseURL]) {
            // here you clean the request
            delete currentExecutingRequests[response.request.responseURL];
        }
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        const { config, response } = error;
        const originalRequest = config;

        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
            // here you check if this is a cancelled request to drop it silently (without error)
            return new Promise(() => {});
        }

        if (currentExecutingRequests[originalRequest.url]) {
            // here you clean the request
            delete currentExecutingRequests[originalRequest.url];
        }

        // here you could check expired token and refresh it if necessary

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you also show how to clean up the canceled request in useEffect?

Comment: Do you mean somenthing like this?
`React.useEffect(() => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    (async () => {
      try {
      
        const response = await axios.get(URL, {
          cancelToken: source.token
        });


        console.log(response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();

    return () => source.cancel();
  }, []);`

You can see it here for more clarification: https://codesandbox.io/s/cancelling-request-in-useeffect-axios-q9cze

Answer (score 4):

As of Axios v0.22.0 an `AbortSignal` is the recommended way to cancel from a **request** interceptor.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (requestConfig) => {
      /* some logic */
      return {
        ...requestConfig,
        signal: AbortSignal.abort()
      };
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work: 1.  AbortSignal must be newed up 2. AbortSignal doesn't have an `abort` function.

Comment: Looks like current approach is to use `AbortController`, which has slightly different syntax: https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: This is the most concise answer so far.

Yet it looks like the [`AbortSignal.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort#browser_compatibility) is __much less supported__ than the `const controller = new AbortController()` -> [`controller.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort#browser_compatibility) sequence.

Answer (score 3):

@[Kirill Taletski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266644/12261182)'s answer solve this perfectly, but add one line:

```js
const CancelToken = Axios.CancelToken;
```

then ,it gonna be like this :

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  /* some logic */
  const CancelToken = Axios.CancelToken;
  return {
    ...config,
    cancelToken: new CancelToken((cancel) => cancel('Cancel repeated request'))
  };
});
```

Comment: should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution

```
import axios from 'axios';

const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {

  if (cancel) {
    cancel(); // cancel request
  }

  config.cancelToken =  new CancelToken(function executor(c)
    {
      cancel = c;
    })

  return config

}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error)
});
```

Comment: I think this is about cancelling a request already running, OP was talking about a not yet started

Comment: What is `let cancel`? And why you're checking if it's true then calling it! I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228288/2051938

`axios.ts`

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: apiBaseUrl });

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    req => {
        const originalRequest = req;
        const cancelUniqId = (originalRequest.cancelToken as unknown) as string;

        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(currentExecutingRequests, cancelUniqId)) {
            const source = currentExecutingRequests[cancelUniqId];
            delete currentExecutingRequests[cancelUniqId];
            source.cancel();
        }

        if (cancelUniqId) {
            const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
            const source = CancelToken.source();
            originalRequest.cancelToken = source.token;
            currentExecutingRequests[cancelUniqId] = source;
        }

        return originalRequest;
    },
    err => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        for (const key of Object.keys(currentExecutingRequests)) {
            if (currentExecutingRequests[key].token === response.config.cancelToken) {
                delete currentExecutingRequests[key];
                break;
            }
        }
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        const { response } = error;

        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
            return new Promise(() => {
                //
            });
        }

        for (const key of Object.keys(currentExecutingRequests)) {
            if (currentExecutingRequests[key].token === response.config.cancelToken) {
                delete currentExecutingRequests[key];
                break;
            }
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export { axiosInstance };
```

Usage:

```
axiosInstance.request({
    url: "some/req/path",
    method: "POST",
    params: {...},
    data: {...},
    cancelToken: "someUniqRequestID" // <-- IMPORTANT!
})
```

as a result, all requests with `someUniqRequestID` token will be cancelled when previous request with SAME `cancelToken` was not finished before.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for axios 0.20.0:

```
const interceptorRequestConfig = (config) => {
    if (sourceRequest[config.url]) {
        sourceRequest[config.url].cancel('Automatic cancellation')
    }

    const axiosSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
    sourceRequest[config.url] = { cancel: axiosSource.cancel }
    config.cancelToken = axiosSource.token

    return config
}
```

credit for the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701130/8840359

Comment: CancelToken is deprecated